# Declare array first, initialize later

Tags: java, arrays

I've got a problem because I need to have access to 2d array `retArray[][]` from other methods but the size of the array is determined in constructor method. Putting it outside the constructor method causes undefined `theYearsNum`and putting in as it is now causes that it can't be seen from another methods. Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
...

public Taxation(int theSalary, int theYear, int theYearsNum, double theLowTaxRate, double theHighTaxRate, int theBoundaryLimit){

    double retArray[][] = new double[theYearsNum][3];

}

// Methods

...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare it as a member and initialize it in the constructor :

```
private double[][] retArray;
public Taxation(int theSalary, int theYear, int theYearsNum, double theLowTaxRate, double theHighTaxRate, int theBoundaryLimit)
{    
    retArray = new double[theYearsNum][3];    
}
```